# Luggage storage in Oxford

Tags: luggage-storage, oxford

When looking to leave luggage somewhere for a few hours in the UK, for larger places my normal go-to is one of the [commercial left luggage places at a large station](http://www.seat61.com/luggage-lockers-at-stations.htm#Left_luggage_in_London), though sadly Oxford isn't one of the places that offer it. Another good option is to leave it where you've just stayed / will be staying, assuming that's the same city that is!

This week, a friend is going to be passing through Oxford for a few hours, and sadly they've timed it for when I'm not there to look after their bags. They're passing through Oxford on their way elsewhere, so don't have accommodation in the city either before or after where bags could be left. They're planning to do a fair bit of walking around the city, which is much less fun dragging a suitcase.

Is there anywhere in Oxford that they would be able to leave their luggage for a few hours? And how much does it cost for a small-ish suitcase?

Comment: they're arriving by train? the best thing you can do is pick up the phone and call the train station (or drop by if you are near), and ask the information staff - they will have the decisive answer

Comment: @JoeBlow The station staff will be able to confirm they don't offer it there, which I already know, not sure they'd know anything about external options as their main role is telling you about trains not tourist things!

Comment: Gagra -- Gotchya!  I bet, it would be a pretty common question?  You never know, someone there may know.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Apparently Oxford Backpackers will hold on to them for you, for a fee:

> Oxford Backpackers, 9A Hythe Bridge Street, will accept left-luggage
>   even from non-residents at 2 pounds per person per day - but not
>   necessarily per item, if two items can be tied together. Remember,
>   however, that you have to climb a flight of stairs to start with.

This from a [link on tripadvisor](http://www.tripadvisor.com.sg/ShowTopic-g186361-i440-k163748-Oxford_Lockers_or_left_luggage_near_train_or_bus_station-Oxford_Oxfordshire_England.html) that I was reading. The hostel is just a few minutes walk from the station, according to the page.

Answer (score 5):

Just returned from Oxford July 2015. Backpackers Hostel on Hythe Bridge street will hold luggage for the day. They charge £ 4 per item. Is about 1 block from train station. Caution there is a very steep long staircase to get into hostel. Staff was very friendly and welcoming!